# DynamoDB delete trigger OldImage

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to do some cleanup after a record has been deleted in my DynamoDB table. It would be pretty great if I could use triggers to do this. Unfortunately it seems that OldImage is not passed into "REMOVE" events. The problem is that I need some record attributes other than the keys in order to perform my cleanup and I can't actually read the record anymore to get these attributes once the event has triggered. Is there any other way I can still read attributes of a record that has been deleted in a trigger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the DynamoDB stream to include new and old images.

Comment: Where can I do that?

Comment: No worries, I found it, never new it was a setting.